# Vulnerabity Libpng library

Tags: android, libpng, android-security, google-console-developer

I'm using this library for scanning and cropping images but after publishing my apk in the google console developer I get this alert and the apk is rejected :

> Libpng library  The vulnerabilities were fixed in libpng v1.0.66,
>   v.1.2.56, v.1.4.19, v1.5.26 or higher. You can find more information
>   about how resolve the issue in this Google Help Center article.

I tried updating openCV to 3.1 but still get the same message.

Probably the problem comes from these because they're pre-compiled with an older version of OpenCV

> \app\src\main\libs\armeabi-v7a\libopencv_java.so
>
> \app\src\main\libs\armeabi-v7a\libScanner.so

If there's a way to re-compile these files and get the new .so I think it is the solution for that problem.

IDE : Android Studio

LIBRARY : https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo

Comment: Library is now upgraded to OpenCV 3.1, hopefully you should not be seeing this errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this sollution i found it on OpenCV site:

http://answers.opencv.org/question/98805/need-update-opencv-manager-apk-for-google-play-warning/